# How can I access an scalar iside a hash atribute of a class in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I am still learning some object oriented perl and I am struggling a bit on how to access my classes.

I've successfully created a class which one of its attributes is a hash. When I want print directly the value of a given key in this hash, the output is always blank. If I assign a new variable to the value of the hash, then I can print this variable.

Toy example code:

```
 sub new {  
    my($clas) = @_;
    my($self) = {}; 

    bless($self,$clas);
    $self->{age_record} = {};
    return($self);  
}
```

Imaginary code that fills up my hash

```
my $class->new("class");
fill_hash($class);
```

Let's use Data::Dumper to see what's in the hash.

```
print Dumper $class->{age_record};
$VAR1 = {
         'Rigobert' => 17,
         'Helene' => 42
       };
```

I get nothing if I print directly.

```
 print $class->{age_record}{'Rigobert'};
```

But if I asign it first to a new variable, it works.

```
my $age = $class->{age_record}{'Rigobert'};
print "Age is : $age\n";
```

I get

```
Age is : 17
```

What am I doing wrong when referencing the hash attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see there is nothing wrong, and the only reason I can think of for your output not appearing is that it is buffered. You should try adding

```
STDOUT->autoflush;
```

near the top of your program.

However, you shouldn't be accessing internal data structures from the calling code. `fill_hash` should be a better_named *method* and you need to write an *accessor method* to get to the `age_record` element. Something like this

```
sub pupil_age {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($name) = @_;
    $self->{age_record}{$name};
}
```

and then you can call it as

```
printf "Age is : %d\n", $class->pupil_age('Rigobert');
```

(The `printf` is just a style choice — there's no other need to use it above a simple `print`)

Comment: Thanks Borodin. I appreciate your suggestions to improve my coding style. It makes much more sense to have a nice accessor routine.

Comment: @pedrosaurio: It's *essential* to provide the *encapsulation* design pattern that is very important in object-oriented programming. If you access the internals of an object directly then you are breaking that encapsulation, with the effect that any changes to the internal operation of the class may break the calling code. If there is an accessor method then only that needs to be changed to keep external code running smoothly

Comment: @pedrosaurio:  Did you fix your original problem yet?

Comment: It seems that it was not buffered as `STDOUT->autoflush;` didn't help.
I generated an accessor method as you suggested and there I am cheating as I first assign the value of my hash to a dummy variable which is returned by the accessor method.

Comment: @pedrosaurio: There is nothing about assigning to an intermediate variable that will change what is printed. Perhaps you misspelled the hash key in the first case? Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in place? Can you please show your complete code so that we can resolve this properly?

Comment: @pedrosaurio: You should always `use warnings` as well, and expect to eliminate any warnings that are raised when your code runs. Thanks for the code. I've been out all day so will take a look tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled by the line

```
my $class->new("class");
```

It should be something like:

```
my $class = Class->new();
```

(Assuming that your class's name is "Class" - it's pretty confusing having a class called "Class". I'm assuming that you have class modelling an academic class!)

Then you'd have a method to add a pupil.

```
sub add_pupil {
  my ($self, $name, $age) = @_;

  $self->{age_record}{$name} = $age;
}
```

And another method to get a pupil.

```
sub get_pupil {
  my ($self, $name) = @_;

  return $self->{age_record}{$name};
}
```

You'd then use it like this.

```
my $class = Class->new();
$class->add_pupil('Rigobert', 17);
$class->add_pupil('Helene', 42);

print $class->get_pupil('Rigobert'); # prints 17
```

I think you're confused because you haven't really thought about how you are modelling your data inside the class. And I can't be much more help as I don't know what the other attributes are or what your `fill_hash()` subroutine looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Dave. My code is much more complex so I just made a quick n' dirty example of what my problem is. As I didn't pay too much attention on what name to give to the class and I just named it "class". The academic class thingy kind of evolved from the example that Borodin wrote. I will try your suggested code and find out if it works out for me.